# Install C++ for visual studio 2022 on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022, xamarin-studio

Is there any way to install c++ for visual studio 2022 on macOS? From the product page at Microsoft https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/ Visual Studio for Mac appears to support only .Net development.

> Visual Studio for Mac
> Develop apps and games for iOS, Android, and the web using .NET.

I'm looking for a way to develop desktop application using c++ so if there's no way downloading it then is there any way to develop c++ based software ( wxWidgets, cmake, c++)?? Thanks.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang (and probably others as well) are available as C++ compilers on Mac - You don't need Visual Studio to write C++ programs on/for Mac.

Answer (score 7):

## Alternative Solutions

### Visual Studio for Mac

Visual Studio for Mac is not the same product as VS for Windows. It's a re-branded [Xamarin Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#Xamarin_Studio). It's an entirely different product mainly meant for mobile and Web apps, It recently picked up proper .NET support as they moved everything from .NET Framework to .NET Core (now just called .NET).

Unfortunately, they've [announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/)  the retirement of the product.

### VS Code

As the first alternative the [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) should work well with C++ and a proper compiler and build toolchain. But of course, it's not like an IDE. Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) and Visual Studio Code is a rich text editor like Sublime Text and Atom. But the difference between the tools is more than just IDE and text editor. An IDE is a robust tool for writing, editing, debugging, testing, and running your code. A text editor only lets you write and edit your code. You might have to step out of a text editor to run your code or download plugins to help it do the running for you. There are good plugins for VS Code for sure. But remember, you can write code with other text editors and use plugins as well. I can tell the experience is not the same.

You can follow [this documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/setting-up-visual-studio-code-for-unreal-engine/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20debugging%20on,the%20change%20to%20take%20effect.) to install VS Code for your preferred system. Also, check this for [Using Clang in Visual Studio Code for macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

VS Code is **not recommended for beginners**!

### Xcode

Try the [Xcode](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)! Xcode is the main IDE of the macOS platform. Xcode provides developers with a unified workflow for user interface design, coding, testing, and debugging on the [macOS](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

Apple supports C++ with the Apple Clang compiler (included in Xcode) and the libc++ C++ standard library runtime (included in SDKs and operating systems). The compiler and runtime are regularly updated to offer new functionality, including many leading-edge features specified by the ISO C++ standard.

### QtCreator

If you are familiar with the [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/download), and use it for any other development purpose,  you might want to use it for Unreal Engine as well. Also, QT Creator could be a choice especially if you're on Linux. But there is a **Warning Message** on the [Unreal documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpQtCreator/).

> At Epic, we used this information to help set up QtCreator for use
> with Unreal Engine, and while we provide this document as a courtesy,
> The level of support we can offer for QtCreator is limited to Unreal
> Engine 4.14

So, please share your personal experience in the comments below. (Thank you for sharing @JesperJuhl)

### Rider

[Rider for Unreal](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/rider-unreal/) is a non-free option for C++ and Unreal Engine from JetBrains. If you use one of the tools of the JetBrains it's the same experience. So, if your company has a license, you can continue from there. It's a really great tool in general for both C++ and Unreal Engine. It gives you insights on [Blueprints](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/GettingStarted/), assists with the [reflection mechanism](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/reflection-system-in-unreal-engine/), and helps ensure good coding style and accuracy.

### Additional Information

- Visual Studio for Mac [Retirement Announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/)
- Xcode 15 RC Release Notes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes/

Comment: QtCreator is also a rather nice IDE that's available on Mac. But all you really need is a text editor and a compiler. I personally wouldn't recommend VSCode to beginners - it's not a very beginner friendly editor (at least not for C++).